# setting CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, buildpack

I need to install a specific version of chromedriver on heroku because of mismatch between latest chromedriver and google chrome. On their website it says that:

> You can control the specific version by setting the
> CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION variable to an explicit version e.g. 2.39

But where do I put this variable? How do I pass it over?

Answer (score 4):

I was finally able to solve it. I logged in to heroku-cli and set env variable through there, e.g:

```
heroku config:set CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=89.0.4389.23 --app myAppName
```

Comment: Did you do anything special after setting the variable? I'm having this problem right now and sadly just setting it hasn't helped.